# npm replaces "^" with "/Users/myusername" on macOS

Tags: macos, npm, node-modules, package.json

Whenever I install a npm package, instead of showing as it should, like "co-body": "^4.2.0" it is added like "co-body": "/Users/username4.2.0".

I am using the latest version of npm available (3.10.8), on macOS Sierra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use: `npm config set save-prefix "^"`.

Comment: Works great. For some reason, the npm config set save-prefix="^" was not working.